# Tkinter - How to remove white background of pictures of buttons and in general

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm pretty new to Tkinter and I have made for a program a screen of buttons that, when pressed, do a command.

Picture of the screen:

[image]

I'm using the pictures with the buttons. The background of the photos make the screen look aesthetically unpleasing, so I have there's a way to remove the white background of the pictures.

Any advice would be appreciated! thank you very much in advance.

Also, here is how I put those image on the screen with the button (example given is keyboard image):

```
keyb_img = resize_img('/ServerImages/KeyBPhoto.jpg', 100)
self.keyb_img = keyb_img
keyb_share_button = Button(self.top_level, image=self.keyb_img, command=lambda: self.keyb_press('Keyboard_Change'), borderwidth=0).grid(row=2, column=5, pady=100, padx =15)
```

Comment: Can you please show us your `resize_img` function?

Comment: `.jpg` images don't have transparent backgrounds so the easiest is to just convert those images to `.png` and make the background transparent for those (there actually is a website or two for doing exactly that), otherwise don't think it is too simple, maybe using `.attributes` and then setting some color to transparent don't know if it works for images like this tho

Comment: as Matiss said, you need transparent png.

Comment: TheLizzard, the resize_img function is a function from tkinter. about the png Matiiss I will try right now

Comment: By the way, do you have any other advice on how to improve the GUI? I would like to hear everything ^^

Comment: advice: a common mistake is doing this (as you have done): `keyb_share_button = Button(self.top_level, image=self.keyb_img, command=lambda: self.keyb_press('Keyboard_Change'), borderwidth=0).grid(row=2, column=5, pady=100, padx =15)`. this line works and will display the button and all, the issue (and this is relatable to all widgets in tkinter) is that layout managers like `.pack()`, `.grid()` and `place()` return None so what does that mean? it means that the value of the variable in this case `keyb_share_button` is `None` so it would be the same as `keyb_share_button = None`

Comment: which is pointless as You can see since that variable can't really be used. Two solutions would be to either don't use a variable at all like this: `Button(self.top_level, image=self.keyb_img, command=lambda: self.keyb_press('Keyboard_Change'), borderwidth=0).grid(row=2, column=5, pady=100, padx =15)` because it will be then less confusing since You will be less likely to mistakenly use that variable

Comment: or split into two lines like so: `keyb_share_button = Button(self.top_level, image=self.keyb_img, command=lambda: self.keyb_press('Keyboard_Change'), borderwidth=0)` and `keyb_share_button.grid(row=2, column=5, pady=100, padx =15)` which will allow You to use that variable and it will contain the Button widget instance so You will be able to actually interact with that exact widget instance. Why am I telling YOu this? because this issue causes a lot of errors that get asked here

Comment: tkinter `Button` widget does not support transparent background even though a transparent image like PNG is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Matiiss pointed out: *`.jpg` images don't have transparent backgrounds*.

So we have to remove the background from the image. To do that we can use [PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

width = 100
height = 100

image = Image.open("/ServerImages/KeyBPhoto.jpg").convert("RGBA")
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.LANCZOS)

# Load the pizels into memory
pixels = image.load()

# For each pixel in the image
for i in range(image.size[0]):
    for j in range(image.size[1]):
        # If the pixel is white
        if pixels[i, j] == (255, 255, 255, 255):
            # Make it transparent
            pixels[i, j] = (255, 255, 255, 0)

# Save the now transparent image:
image.save("new_image.png", format="png")

# Show it on the screen
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="red")
canvas.pack()

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_image, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

Please note that this will only convert the pure while pixels into transparent. If a pixel has a value of `#fffffe` (pure white is `#ffffff`), the program will ignore it. Also it will convert all while pixels.

---

**EDIT:** by @furas

If you would use `numpy array` then it could be shorter

```
import numpy as np

# convert pillow.Image to numpy.array
array = np.array(image)  

mask = np.all(array == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=-1)  # png without artefacts
array[ mask ] = [255, 255, 255, 0]

# convert numpy.array to pillow.Image
image = Image.fromarray(array)
```

But `JPG` may have artefacts like `#fffffe` instead of pure white `#ffffff` and then you can use mask with `>=`

```
mask = np.all(array >= [230, 230, 230, 255], axis=-1)  # jpg with artefacts
```

---

Minimal working code:

I first remove color and later resize it to reduce artefacts.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np

def convert_pillow(image):
    #print('[DEBUG] convert_pillow')
    
    # Load the pizels into memory
    pixels = image.load()
    
    # For each pixel in the image
    for i in range(image.size[0]):
        for j in range(image.size[1]):
            # If the pixel is white
            if pixels[i, j] == (255, 255, 255, 255):
                # Make it transparent
                pixels[i, j] = (255, 255, 255, 0)

    return image
    
def convert_numpy(image):
    #print('[DEBUG] convert_numpy')
    import numpy as np

    # convert pillow.Image to numpy.array
    array = np.array(image)  
    
    #mask = np.all(array == [255, 255, 255, 255], axis=-1)  # png without artefacts
    mask = np.all(array >= [230, 230, 230, 255], axis=-1)  # jpg with artefacts
    array[ mask ] = [255, 255, 255, 0]

    # convert numpy.array to pillow.Image
    image = Image.fromarray(array)
    
    return image

# --- main ---

width = 100
height = 100

filename = "test/rgb.png"
filename = "test/rgb.jpg"
image = Image.open(filename).convert("RGBA")

#image = convert_pillow(image)
image = convert_numpy(image)

# resize after changing color - because resize creates new artefacts
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.LANCZOS)

# Save the now transparent image:
image.save("new_image.png", format="png")

# Show it on the screen
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="gray")
canvas.pack()

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_image, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

Images for tests:

`rgb.png`

[image]

`rgb.jpg`

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Basically its not the best of idea to remove all the white from the image. I recommend the OP to manually do this with an image editing software, also it is worth mentioning that RGBA images can be shown with `create_image()` only and not a label.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am using `create_image` for that reason. Also I had no editing programs on my computer except MS Paint, but I don't know how to force transparency there. That is why I developed this program but yes using an editing software is better.

Comment: It is good alternative if you don't have program to create transparent image - but I would use this code to create program which only converters all `JPG` to transparent `PNG` and later in original program `tkinter` I would use already converted `PNG`. I don't know how fast work this method but converting images only once would be faster. Probably if you would use `numpy.array` then you could write it without `for`-loop - like `pixels[ pixels == (255, 255, 255, 255) ] = (255, 255, 255, 0)` - and it could run faster then with `for`-loop

Comment: @furas Can you please edit my answer to include the `numpy` implementation because I haven't used `numpy` outside of neural networks.

Comment: I added example with numpy, plus some images for test - now everyone can copy code and images to test it.