# How to remove background colour of image in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

here cherri image on main window is in png but still its covering lots of space ?i want to remove that white background

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root=Tk()

root.geometry('600x650+400+20')
root.title('C H E R R I')
bgimage = PhotoImage(file='Images/bg.png')
bgLabel = Label(root,image=bgimage)
bgLabel.place(x=-1,y=0)

#Create a canvas
canvas= Canvas(root, width= 600, height= 400)
canvas.pack()
img= (Image.open("Images/Login1.png"))
resized_image= img.resize((270,180), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
canvas.create_image(160,70, anchor=NW, image=new_image)
 
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - How to remove white background of pictures of buttons and in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991787/tkinter-how-to-remove-white-background-of-pictures-of-buttons-and-in-general)

Comment: You can make the background of the PNG image transparent and then directly use it. You could use this [Online PNG Utility](https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png) for the same.

Comment: edit image in some editor (Photoshop, GIMP, etc.) and create PNG with transparent background.

Comment: The white background is the background color of the canvas.  You need to put both the background image and the cherri image inside the canvas.